# Fancybox Ajax not loading in IE

Tags: jquery

I have an issue the Fancybox Ajax.

It works fine in FF, but not in IE7. The popup layout breaks and content didn't load.

You can see it here: http://www.sumsy.com/temp/templatesys/config.php?template=1

Basically, on my php page, it has the following content:

```
<div id="content">
     <a href="config.php?template=1">Template 1</a>
     <a href="config.php?template=2">Template 2</a>
     </div>
```

On another page, I call it by using:

```
<a id="changeTemplate" href="modules/templateList.php">Change Template</a>
```

Not sure why it is not showing up properly in IE7.
If i use iframe (class="iframe") instead, then it works fine.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

'height'                : 'auto',

for ur javascript, remove the comma. it should not be there if it is the last one.

sorry that i did not read the rest of your question. As far as i know, fancybox requires you to specific whether is it a iframe or not. Try something like this

```
$(".frame_modal_box").fancybox({
'width'         : 350,
'autoScale'         : true,
'centerOnScroll'    : true,
'type'          : 'iframe'
});
```

Comment: I have removed the comma, tried it in my localhost. But it still does not work.

Comment: i have edited the answer. Try out the script. let me know if it doesnt work well.

Comment: iframe works fine. But I dont want to use iframe, as the URLs the popup conent would be different (they are relative path urls). Thats why I want to use Ajax

Comment: it seems like your iframe is affecting the script. try removing the <iframe id='templateframe' name='templateframe' src="templates/template1/login.html"></iframe>

Comment: Hi, lilsizzo.
You are right. After I removed that iframe, it works fine. But why was that? Any work around? I need to keep that iframe.

Comment: try putting the iframe within your controlWrapper div. that should be working. does your iframe has the html head body tags?